# Receiving Arguments via Pointers in Python

Tags: python, arguments

I have a class whose function defined like this. My intention is to send multiple arguments to it .

For testing, I called it as `:class_name("argument1","argument2")`, and it says: `__init__accepts atmost 1 arguments , 3 given`

```
def __init__(self, **options):
    for name in options:
        self.__dict__[name] = options[name]
```

What is the proper way to handle this ?

Any suggestions welcome......

Comment: N.B: `*` **does not** represent a pointer in Python.

Comment: That is [a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656178/how-do-you-articulate-the-and-specifiers-when-reading-python-aloud)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use one asterisk instead of two.  Double asterisks are for named arguments.  There is a nice explanation in the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) if you are interested in reading further.

```
def __init__(self, *options):
    for name in options:
        self.__dict__[name] = name
```

However, from your code I think the real issue is that you are calling your function incorrectly.

You would want to call it like:

```
class_name(argument1="some value")

def __init__(self, **options):
    for name,val in options.iteritems():
        self.__dict__[name] = val
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simpler way to write it

```
def __init__(self, **options):
    vars(self).update(options)
```

Comment: @gnibbler - the Python docs warn against modifying the dict returned by `vars` - see http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars

Comment: @A Lee, when `vars` is called without an argument is is equivalent to `locals()`, and this result should not be modified. In the case of an instance, it simply returns the `__dict__` which is of course ok to modify.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` form collects positional arguments:

```
def __init__(self, *options):
```

and the `**` form collects keyword arguments:

```
def __init__(self, **options):
```

You're providing 2 positional arguments plus the instance as `self`, but it's defined to expect only 1 positional argument `self`.