# Do Python's `*` and `**` specifiers have a name?

Tags: python, naming, keyword-argument, args

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [proper name for python * operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator)

`*` is clearly used when unpacking [an arbitrary number of arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and

`**` is used when unpacking [keyword arguments as a dictionary](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameters-from-one-function-to-another).

It is [conventional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) to use `*args` and `**kwargs`, and I tend to pronounce these as "args" and "quargs", ignoring the `*`s.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645311/receiving-arguments-via-pointers-in-python/6645440#comment-7852637), the asterisk was referred to as a *pointer*.

How does the [BDFL](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-bdfl) refer to these symbols?

---

### Following closure.

Thanks for finding the linked question, this is what I was looking for. It's really tricky to search (even very specific areas of) the web accurately for `*`!

To the commentators who responded with how they pronounce "*", that was not the question I was asking (and apologies if my question mislead you). What I wanted to know is how these specifiers are named **in Python**, this was not a subjective question (hence the reference to the BDFL).

Comment: I've always heard it called "splat", as per <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator>.

Comment: I think `**` is called splooge. I could be wrong though.

Comment: "In this question, the asterisk was referred to as a pointer." What a terrible mistake that was.  Try to ignore it.  It's far from appropriate.

Comment: They are not really pointers really more expansions

Comment: @Radu - would that make `~**` a squiggly-splooge?

Comment: Personally, I call just call it args and kwargs (like you)...as for what the BDFL calls it, good luck with that (although I guess it's not inconceivable someone here has actually heard him refer to these).

Comment: For my part, I found articulating `*` as `all` works for shell glob patterns, regexes *and* Python arguments: `all args`, `all quargs`.

Comment: How about splat (`*`) and double-splat (`**`) ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, have added some more information to my question. It's really tricky to search the (even very specific areas of) web accurately for '*'!